# getText().toString() вызывается устаревшее значение

Tags: java, android

Есть такая конструкция

```
 int parse_txtw = Integer.parseInt(getString(R.string.value));
            view.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(spinervalue)*parse_txtw));
```

Затем , когда я пытаюсь вызвать значение из другого класса с помощью`view.getText().toString()`, то вызывается изначальное, не актуальное значение из R.string,а нужно новое, в зависимости от выставляемого значения в спинере и его умножения.

Переформулирую вопрос и опишу другим способом. есть textview, я присваиваю ему значение в разметке `android:text="0"`  по умолчанию, до арфиметических операций, затем код подхватывает дефолтный строковый ресурс  `<string name="textview222">77</string>`, делает операции, и допустим в сумме выходит 100 и задается этому же textview, и вместо 0, присваивается 100, что логично и работает как надо , но до того момента когда я хочу вытянуть эти 100 из другого класса с помощью getText().toString(), вместо 100 вытягивается 0, изначальное значение.

Вот кусок где идет обращение

```
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> map;

    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("key", txtwiew.getText().toString());
    myArrList.add(map);
```

Comment: Значения в классе R записываются на этапе компиляции и во время исполнения не могут быть изменены. Попробуйте переформулировать вопрос - в данный момент вы описываете невозможную ситуацию и то очень туманно

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Описал подробнее в теле письма. Надеюсь Вы меня поняли)

Comment: Видимо вы создаёте новый экземпляр текстового поля вместо обращения к имеющемуся. Покажите как вы получаете ссылку на текстовое поле для отбирания его значения

Comment: @ЮрийСПб обновил

Comment: Покажите не как вы используете текстовое поле, а где и как его инициализируете.

Comment: Вам нужно получать значение в переменную внутри первого класса и потом явно передавать ее в другой класс. Если активити не видима на экране, ее виджеты больше не существуют и значения в них будут утрачены.

Comment: Вопрос решен, спасибо, явная передача работает.